# Using Django reduce(or_) - How can I store an unmatched query with 0 results in a variable

Tags: django, django-filter, django-q

I have a function that takes a user's input from a list of data and searches my database for any items that matches the user's input, and returns all results that are in my database:

```
results = results.filter(
        reduce(or_, (Q(name__icontains=itm.strip()) for itm in query))
    )
```

I would like to handle cases where the user's input is not present in my database. since `results` fitlers down to what exists, how can I check if the above code failed to find at least one matching result for a query, and store that query in a variable? For example, if `results` queried my database for the following list: ['one', 'two', 'thee'], assuming 'thee' is not in my database but the other two are, I would like to store the string "thee" in a variable to use later

Answer (score 0):

You can simply evaluate `results` as a Boolean:

```
if not results:
    print('No match found.')
```

From [`QuerySet`'s documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet):

> **`bool()`**. Testing a `QuerySet` in a boolean context, such as using `bool()`,
>   `or`, `and` or an `if` statement, will cause the query to be executed. If
>   there is at least one result, the `QuerySet` is `True`, otherwise `False`.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> if Entry.objects.filter(headline="Test"):
>     print("There is at least one Entry with the headline Test")
> ```

Comment: I should have specified. Results will query each item in a list of user-given data. In this list of the following list of inputs to be queried: `['one', 'two', 'thee']` If for example, "thee" was not in my database, I want to store that string in a variable.  Using `bool()` on results will return True if "one" or "two" is in my database

Answer (score 0):

You can add one query for query:

For example:

query = query.append(Q(name__isnull=True)) or something that always False

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do it one piece of code:

```
results = results.filter(
    reduce(or_, (Q(name__icontains=itm.strip()) for itm in query))
)
```

I iterated over each item in query and checked if it exists

```
for each in query:
    r = results.filter(name__icontains=each)
    if r.exists() == False:
        Do something with each
```

Though not as efficient as I'd like, it solves the problem for now